What`s this? (Found among circulating tumor cells)

I filter circulating tumor cells out of patients blood with metastatic breast cancer using track-etched membrane. I've stumbled upon this... cluster(?) of cells and can`t get what it is. "Greenish" circles are the pores of the membrane of size ~6,5 - 7 um.

The cells you're asking about are neutrophils in varying stages of maturity. Neutrophils are the most abundant of leukocytes, and frequently found in cancerous tissue. Note first that they are all about the same size and stain similarly.
The most segmented of the cells are Polymorphonuclear neutrophils (PMN), of which I count two, and a third that's almost there. There is one band cell (a stage before becoming segmented), one precursor that is starting to become a band (a metamyelocyte), and the immature forms, the myelocytes (two of them). There's also some damaged cells that I won't try to identify.

The photograph is from Cornell University's ECLINPATH page.
See also this page.
If you google neutrophils and cancer, you'll see how they come to be present.
Histology!!! I love it! Always have, always will.

Aren't there four myelocytes in the main cluster? (Perhaps the ones that you called damaged)

@Hedgehog - Probably, but as it's damaged, I'd rather not consider it. If it were critical, I might, but it's not (I presume!).

It`s ... semi-critical - we are trying to determine whether they are circulating tumor cells or not (without immunofluorescent staining)...
